# Radius/nearest results - Google Maps API

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

First of all I'm using Google Maps API v3. I have one big map that shows all the results pulled from a database, now I like to implement a feature that shows a radius of nearest results within X kilometres from the current location (served by HTML5 geolocation).

As the map contains all the results, I want to be able to add X kilometres, then it will get submitted that results will be returned the nearest results according to the current location of the user. The whole map should then remove all the *out-of-radius* markers, leaving the markers that are inside a radius of X kilometres.

I'm requesting an effective code, tutorial or an article on how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the [JSFiddle Demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/3feUC/)

I suppose this is one way to do it.  You can use [Google Map V3 API's circle](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Circle) to create the bounds from your center point or current location.  You can specify the radius of the circle in meters with `setRadius(radius:number)`.  With the created circle you can loop through your markers and see if they are within the circle's bound using [Circle's getBounds object which is a LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) and check if the marker is within bound or not.

I went ahead and created a small demo that has five points on a map, and when you click on the create circle button it'll make the first marker the center point and draws a circle with a radius of 5000 and filters out the markers that are not with in bound using the method described above:

```
function createRadius(dist) {
    var myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: markerArray[markerArray.length - 1].getPosition(),
        map: map,
        radius: dist,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    var myBounds = myCircle.getBounds();

    //filters markers
    for(var i=markerArray.length;i--;){
         if(!myBounds.contains(markerArray[i].getPosition()))
             markerArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    map.setCenter(markerArray[markerArray.length - 1].getPosition());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
}
```

Comment: Sidenote on your example @JSFiddleDemo: With every click of the button, you zoom in again and remove opacity.

Answer (score 1):

This solution just has one major flaw - it fetches data in a rectangle, not in a circle.

If you don't want to query any more data than required - use the [haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) in SQL:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (3959 *
        acos(
            cos(radians(37)) *
            cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(lng) - radians(-122)) +
            sin(radians(37)) *
            sin(radians(lat))
        )
    ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Also checkout [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#creating-the-table)