# Postcode search using the codeigniter google-maps-api-v3-library

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, google-maps-api-3

I use [THIS](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library) awesome library for codeigniter.
I have a website (http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl) when the user first visits the page they have to fill in their postcode and a radius. (this does not do anything yet).
the postcode and radius are saved as a cookie and shown on the mainpage in the searchbar.

I also have factories stored in a table in my database.

the table looks like this:

```
factories
---------
idfactories
factoryname
address
postcode
city
website
email
...
...
```

how can I search for the factory based on the postcode I've stored in the table?

Hope it's a bit clear what I want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radius/nearest results - Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755905/radius-nearest-results-google-maps-api)

Comment: no it isn't. that question is way more further than what i am. i jsut need to know what i've asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native zip code support with the Maps API. You'd have to do something like map all the factories' latitude and longitude then do radius search off that. In the marked duplicate post, there is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/3feUC/) example showing how the circle/radius search works - just change the locations array in there with the factories.

```
function createRadius(dist) {
    var myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: markerArray[markerArray.length - 1].getPosition(),
        map: map,
        radius: dist,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    var myBounds = myCircle.getBounds();

    //filters markers
    for(var i=markerArray.length;i--;){
         if(!myBounds.contains(markerArray[i].getPosition()))
             markerArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    map.setCenter(markerArray[markerArray.length - 1].getPosition());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
}
```

Comment: thanks. but i tried a lot with this api but it does not work for my needs. i think i just need to download a database with postcodes and their lat/long and just use the query with the distance in mysql. thanks anyway.

Comment: fixed it with pro6pp a postcode database with several api's. so i don't need this anymore