# How to get the nearest location by using latitude, longitude and radius in php

Tags: php

I am getting inputs as latitude, longitude and radius. So based on these values I need to find the surroundings values and need to draw the rectangle shape on google map.

Comment: surrounding values? means?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch something from db?

Comment: @user3335742 you mean nearest round figure ?

Comment: Not from db.. I need to find in php

Comment: @Sagar, yes. I need to find the nearest areas

Comment: You can't find nearest location in php, you have to use google location api for nearest location.

Comment: @user3335742 , you mean 1.55577 will give 2, right ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755905/radius-nearest-results-google-maps-api

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan, ok, is it possible to get nearest values around 1 km for given latitude and longitude